# Jenkins + artifactory build info with containers and dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, linux-containers

I'm using a build agent which is from a dockerfile.  I have jenkins with the artefactory plugin.

I would like to include the "FROM" statement in the dockerfile to my artifactory so that the build dependencies include the container (aka build environment) too.  (I'm collecting everything through the maven build through the plugin then using the rtPublishBuildInfo to collate it together through all pipeline steps)

Today I can manually add an rtDockerPull command to the pipeline with the same line, but I can't quite work out if there is an automatic way to do this.  I'm using a declarative pipeline so that does tie my hands slightly too.

I'm doing this in a corporate environment, what I need is somethign that is as flexible and "standard" as possible.  Has anyone had to solve this problem before?

Comment: Hey, could you please explain the motivation behind collecting the agent's docker image?
Moreover, we currently working on a new command to JFrog-CLI ([build-docker-create](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/pull/909)) which collects the image's build info in Artifactory and add them as artifacts.
Please let me know your opinion regarding this.

Comment: There are domains particularly in avionics where reproducible builds form part of the safety case.  Having thebdocker build in the dependency graph to me just brings the container into the same dependencies, to build this pipeline i require these inputs.